# Not able to login into rottentomatoes.com using mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I am using following code :-

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/user/account/login/") do |login_page|
  inside_page = login_page.form_with(:action => 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/user/account/login/') do |f|
    f.login_username = "random@mailinator.com"
    f.login_password = "123456"
  end.click_button
end
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any issue with your code, the issue is how Rotten Tomatoes handles a login, they redirect back to the homepage via JavaScript in the HTML body. I added a single line to your code (and added my credentials):

`puts agent.page.body`

*The Result:*

```
<script>
    window.top.location='http://www.rottentomatoes.com/';
</script>
```

So, you can either use their [API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/) or if you want to proceed and execute the JavaScript to follow the redirect you can use [WATIR](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).